# LottieAnimation with compose not restarting when the animation is changed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, lottie

I have currently building a Composable-component with an animation that should change based on some state delivered from the ViewModel as a Flow. For the animation I am using LottieCompose v.5.2.0.

My requirements are that the running animation should run indefinite, and when the animation is swapped the new one starts from the beginning.

My problem now is that when the animation is changed the new animation seems to inherit the progress from the previous animation.

```
{
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(spec = LottieCompositionSpec.Asset(state.animation))

    LottieAnimation(
        composition = composition,
        restartOnPlay = true,
        iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
    )
}
```

`state.animation` is a string that is referencing to a animation-asset.

From the source-code I can see that this logic beneath is applied, so with that in mind I assumed that the animation would restart whenever I swapped out the animation.

```
{
    if (isPlaying && !wasPlaying && restartOnPlay) {
        animatable.resetToBeginning()
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a way of solving this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just chiming in here in case it helps anyone else -
I thought I had encountered the same issue however I was the issue ;D

When setting up your composition and following basic usage, your progress using `animateLottieCompositionAsState` such as below:

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.message_from_bottle))
    val progress: Float by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
        composition = composition,
        isPlaying = isPlaying, // ❗️this variable is driven by what ever your requirements are (mutableStateOf / viewmodel state, etc.)
        restartOnPlay = true,
        iterations = 1,
        cancellationBehavior = LottieCancellationBehavior.OnIterationFinish
    )
```

You need to be sure to USE THAT resulting `progress` in how you configure your LottieAnimation, such as so:

````
LottieAnimation(
            composition = composition,
            progress = { progress }, // <-- if you don't do this, your animation will NOT restart 
            ...,
        )
    ```
````